# If a file is not received how to put in warning status?

Tags: shell-script, shell

This is the file received by us everyday
"$DATA_FILE" = "DRM_PROD_APC_TO_WWAPC_EXPORT"

if this file is not received it has to go to warning status.how do i do that in unix shell script?

Comment: You will have to provide a little more detail. How is the file received, how is it checked and how do you want to be warned?

Comment: hi it is received as flat file,currently the code for warning status is not working,it is still putting in error status.getting error in the last line  .Here is the last part of the code                                                                                                          if [ $V_STATUS -eq 2 ]
   then
      exit 2
   else
      exit 0
   fi
else
   echo 'Warring...not found the source.'$DAT_PATH/$DATA_FILE$V_CSV
   exit 1
fi

Comment: If you post the code you have that doesn't work then that would be a good start. We can see exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: What are your $V_STATUS codes? 0=OK, 1=??, 2=??

Comment: 0 = completed,1= warning,2= error

Comment: Can you edit the required part of your script directly into the question? The code you've added in the comment seems to miss some `if` statement, make sure you get everything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have 3 actions based upon 3 conditions of `$V_STATUS` 0, 1 & 2.

It will be easier to code using `case` than multiple `if` statements

```
case "$V_STATUS" in
  0)  echo "Everything is OK! Yippeeee"
      exit 0
      ;;
  1)  echo  "Warning status"
      exit 1
      ;;
  2)  echo  "Error status"
      exit 2
      ;;
  *) echo "Status is unknown!"
     ;;
esac
```